# How to load list columns into a dataframe?

Tags: python, json, list, apache-spark

I try to load "columns" from a python list object into a dataframe.

This is my list object:

```
list = type(api_response.results) -> <class 'list'>
```

These are the values from the list object (I think this is a json structur):

```
{'results': [{'data': [{'interval': '2022-11-11T10:00:00.000Z/2022-11-11T10:30:00.000Z',
                        'metrics': [{'metric': 'nError',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 4,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}},
                                    {'metric': 'nOffered',
                                     'qualifier': None,
                                     'stats': {'count': 113,
                                               'count_negative': None,
                                               'count_positive': None,
                                               'current': None,
                                               'denominator': None,
                                               'max': None,
                                               'min': None,
                                               'numerator': None,
                                               'ratio': None,
                                               'sum': None,
                                               'target': None}}],
                        'views': None}],
              'group': {'mediaType': 'voice'}}]}
```

I just need this result:

```
 Dataframe:
    interval                                            metric      count
 0  2022-11-11T10:00:00.000Z/2022-11-11T10:30:00.000Z   nError      4
 1  2022-11-11T10:00:00.000Z/2022-11-11T10:30:00.000Z   nOffered    113
```

How get this result? How is it possibly to call intervals or metrics from the list object?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
def get_metric(x):
    check=0
    vals=[]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        if len(x)==1:
            check=1
        for j in range(0,len(x) + check):
            print(i,j)
            vals.append(x[i]['data'][0]['metrics'][j]['metric'])
    return vals

def get_count(x):
    vals=[]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        for j in range(0,len(x[0])):
            vals.append(x[i]['data'][0]['metrics'][j]['stats']['count'])
    return vals

df['interval']=df['results'].apply(lambda x: [x[0]['data'][i]['interval'] for i in range(0,len(x[0]['data']))])
df['metric']= df['results'].apply(lambda x: get_metric(x))
df['count']= df['results'].apply(lambda x: get_count(x))
df=df.drop(['results'],axis=1)
df=df.explode(['metric','count']).explode('interval')

print(df)
'''
    interval                                            metric      count
0   2022-11-11T10:00:00.000Z/2022-11-11T10:30:00.000Z   nError      4
0   2022-11-11T10:00:00.000Z/2022-11-11T10:30:00.000Z   nOffered    113

'''
```